# How to make a bot edit its own message in discord php

Tags: php, discord

is someone know how to make BOT edit own message in discordPHP ?

i already created but they always error on Uncaught Error: Call to a member function edit() on null
This is my code :

```
$message->edit(MessageBuilder::new()
            ->setContent('embeds')
            ->setTts(true))->done()
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a slot machine for my bot and I googled for this. But I found it myself.

In my code, I used this:

```php
$msg->reply("Slot is spinning... <a:loading:990300992287424553> \n<a:slotmachine:990303077213012008> <a:slotmachine:990303077213012008> <a:slotmachine:990303077213012008>")->then(function($msg)
{
    if(!($msg instanceof Message)) return $msg->reply("An error excepted.");
    $this->discord->getLoop()->addTimer(3.0, function() use ($msg) {
        $msg->channel->editMessage($msg, "Slot has been spinned. \n:strawberry: :strawberry: :strawberry:");
    });
});
```

You can use this:

```php
$msg->channel->sendMessage("Hello")->then(function($msg){
    $msg->channel->editMessage($msg, "How are u?");
});
```

If you wanna a timeout, you can use like my code.